# Wordpress links have become non-clickable

Tags: wordpress

My blog link was working well before. But today it seems that all the links of the subpages has become non-clickable.

In every wordpress sub pages, none of the links are clickable.. Just check it.. don't know what's the problem...

[wordpress site url](http://blog.cogxio.com/how-can-a-woman-impress-her-first-date/)

When the site was created before it didn't have this kind of issue.. But today when I was checking I found this strange thing.

This problem wasn't before... Anyone help a bit.. I will be thankful..

Answer (score 0):

If you use the element inspector in chrome, you'll see that an `<ul>` size is very big. This one's id is `#social_comments_control .ui-widget-header` which css is located in ur page's wp-content/plugins/social-comments/assets/css/social_comments.css so what comes to my mind is just to add this css to that element id in that stylesheet: `overflow:hidden;` or `height:0`; or just quit its html from the template.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit are these classes and the id:

```
<ul id="social_comments_nav" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
```

Just remove them like this and the links on the page will be clickable again:

```
 <ul role="tablist">
```

**Alternatively:**

In case you want to keep the classes and the id, just simply remove the 'position:relative;' from **#social_comments_nav** and **.ui-tabs.ui-tabs-nav** which are defined in:

```
 /wp-content/plugins/social-comments/assets/css/social_comments.css
```

and the links will be clickable again.